# Group and create three new columns by condition [Low, Hit, High] (pandas equivalent in R)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to adapt some parts of my python code to R and don't know how to solve it there.

I have a large dataset (~5 Mio rows) with results from some ML trainings. Now I want to qualify the results by defining if they hit the "target range". This "target range" contains all values between `-0.25` and `+0.25`. If it's inside this range, it's a `Hit`, if it's below `Low` and `High` on the other side.

```
df = data.frame(Type=c("RF", "RF", "RF", "MLP", "MLP", "MLP"),
               Value=c(-1.5, -0.1, 1.7, 0.2, -0.7, -0.6))
                
df

+--------+---------+
| Type   |   Value |
+--------+---------|
| RF     |    -1.5 | <- Low
| RF     |    -0.1 | <- Hit
| RF     |     1.7 | <- High
| MLP    |     0.2 | <- Hit
| MLP    |    -0.7 | <- Low
| MLP    |    -0.6 | <- Low
+--------+---------+
```

In python python pandas I could solve it with:

```
(df.assign(group=pd.cut(df['Value'],
               [float('-inf'), -0.25, 0.25, float('inf')],
                        labels=['Low', 'Hit', 'High']))
   .pivot_table(index='Type', columns='group', values='Value', aggfunc='count')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

Can somebody help me how I could adapt this to R? Whether `native R`, `data.table` or `dplyr` doesn't matter, I'm open for any approach. Nevertheless as faster as better :-)

---

**Expected output**

```
df_expected = data.frame(Type=c("RF", "MLP"), "Low"=c(1,2), "Hit"=c(1,1), "High"=c(1,0))

+--------+-------+-------+--------+
| Type   |   Low |   Hit |   High |
+--------+-------+-------+--------|
| RF     |     1 |     1 |      1 |
| MLP    |     2 |     1 |      0 |
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that your data are somewhat big. I would use `data.table` for what you need as you'll get results much faster.

This is how I'd construct a script in order to achieve what you want. `data.table`'s optimised functions `fcase` (works like SQL's CASE WHEN) and `dcast` are utilised here while I also create the class `error` to account for observation that do not fall under your predefined conditions.

```
library(data.table)

df = data.frame(Type=c("RF", "RF", "RF", "MLP", "MLP", "MLP"),
                Value=c(-1.5, -0.1, 1.7, 0.2, -0.7, -0.6))

df = as.data.table(df)

df[, class := fcase(Value >= -0.25 & Value <= 0.25, "Hit",
                    Value < -0.25, "Low",
                    Value > 0.25, "High",
                    default = "error")]

dcast(df, Type ~ class, value.var = "class")
```

Output:

```
   Type High Hit Low
1:  MLP    0   1   2
2:   RF    1   1   1
```

Answer (score 3):

The `base::cut()` command can do this:

```
 df$Cut<-cut(df$Value, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, Inf), labels = c("Low", "Hit", "High"), )

 df
  Type Value  Cut
1   RF  -1.5  Low
2   RF  -0.1  Hit
3   RF   1.7 High
4  MLP   0.2  Hit
5  MLP  -0.7  Low
6  MLP  -0.6  Low

 table(df$Type, df$Cut)
     
      Low Hit High
  MLP   2   1    0
  RF    1   1    1
```

Edit 2: the dplyr chain with count and pivot_wider:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(name = cut(Value, 
                   breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, Inf), 
                   labels = c("Low", "Hit", "High"), )) %>% 
  count(Type, name) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = n,
              values_fill = 0)
```

Edit 3: Without count, and using value_fn (Value function)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(name = cut(Value, 
                   breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, Inf), 
                   labels = c("Low", "Hit", "High"), )) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = Value,
              values_fn = length,
              values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a totally different approach using `dplyover::over()` with a named recode list. The recoding part is a bit more laborious compared to `cut()` but we don't need the data rectangling with `pivot_wider()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/
# disclaimer: I'm the maintainer and its not on CRAN

df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(over(list(Low  = c(-Inf, -0.25), 
                      Hit  = c(-0.25, 0.25),
                      High = c(0.25, Inf)),
                 ~ sum(Value > .x[1] & Value < .x[2])
                 )
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Type    Low   Hit  High
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 MLP       2     1     0
#> 2 RF        1     1     1
```

We can also use `cut()` for the recoding part an then use `dplyover::over()`.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(Value = cut(Value,
                     breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, Inf),
                     labels = c("Low", "Hit", "High"))) %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(over(unique(.$Value),
                 ~ sum(Value  == .x)
                 )
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Type    Low   Hit  High
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 MLP       2     1     0
#> 2 RF        1     1     1
```

OPs data

```r
df = data.frame(Type=c("RF", "RF", "RF", "MLP", "MLP", "MLP"),
                Value=c(-1.5, -0.1, 1.7, 0.2, -0.7, -0.6))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your explanation, if I could I would accept all solutions. *upvote*

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
library(data.table)

cases = factor(1:3, 1:3, c("Low", "Hit", "High"))
dcast(setDT(df), Type ~ cases[findInterval(Value, c(-Inf, -.25, .25), TRUE)], fun=length)

     Type   Low   Hit  High
1:    MLP     2     1     0
2:     RF     1     1     1
```